# Pause ads and event when ad clicked

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am working with the Dailymotion JavaScript API. A couple of questions:

- Is there a way to pause ads? the .pause() function pauses the main video but it does not seem to pause ads
- Is there an event which is generated when an ad is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pause ads, only the video can be paused.

Also, no event is generated when an add is clicked.